# Fit WPF Label in User Control to the width of its Content

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF User Control that contains a simple label and rectangle on a grid, looking like this:

```
   <Grid x:Name="Pressbutton">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="14"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Rectangle x:Name="LayerColour" Grid.Column="0" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Width="10" Height="10" Margin="0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="10" MinHeight="10" Visibility="Visible" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label x:Name="DisplayNameLabel" Grid.Column="1" Content="Label"  Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="26" Visibility="Visible" />
    </Grid>
```

Then I am laying these out in a StackPanel, which works fine and using a GridSplitter to divide this list of labels from the other part of the window.

My window looks a little like this:

```
==========================================x
| StackPanel           |   Other Stuff    |
|    PressButton1      |                  |
|    PressButton2      |                  |
|    PressButton3      |                  |
===========================================
```

My problem is that currently the GridSplitter only wants to render in the centre of the Window, and I want the label list to be significantly more narrow. The ideal starting width for the label panel is as wide as the widest label.

I have tried measuring the `ActualWidth` of my User Controls but that is always being set to the width of the containing StackPanel. If I try and measure the width of the Labels those too seem determined to stretch to their maximum possible width. It seems ridiculous that I would have to go through the whole rigmarole of pre-rendering the text of my labels just to get an idea of how wide my labels are supposed to be when the text is right there on the label already, so I assume I am doing something wrong.

How do I find the width of the text on my label, so I can move the GridSplitter to fit the left pane snugly?

Comment: Why do people randomly stick the word "simple" everywhere? Just curious what's meant by it. Anyway, I don't see a grid splitter and I'm not sure what your layout is meant to look like so there's an element of guesswork here, but if you want the Label not to size to the column it's in, set its `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` and it'll auto-size to its content, at the left edge of its parent. If you want to add a little padding inside around the Label's text, set the Label's Padding property.

Comment: *"currently the GridSplitter only wants to render in the centre of the Window"* -- Hm?

Comment: This is the user control which contains a label and a rectangle. The splitter is on the window which contains a stack panel loaded with a list of these labels. I suspect that alignment might be the problem though.

Comment: You need to provide a full picture of what's going on here. I can't figure out what control "the container" refers to or what you want to size it to, or why you can't.

Comment: I use simple to mean "off the shelf, as packaged with the original software, in no way modified in the many horrendous ways that one traditionally modifies UI controls that don't quite do what one wants."

Comment: The HorizontalAlignment was the problem, so you did figure it out correctly. Feel free to add that as an answer if you want to take credit. I've edited the question to clarify as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

I assume based on your "drawing" that you have a Grid with two columns. You can set the first column to Auto width and place your stackpanel there.
Set the second column to width 1*, create a GridSplitter and set its Grid.Column to 1, set a fixed width for it(i usually set it to 10) and set HorizontalAlignment to Left and VerticalAlignment to Stretch.
Should do the trick.